# Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

My Project is using below path to search for tools.jar file [maven dependencies in Build Path section of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVGoJ.png)

even though I am using jdk8.0.292.10 in preferences and also in the libraries section of build path. And i checked Lib folder of my jdk8.0.292.10 is having tools.jar files even though my project is not picking it up somehow. PFB the required screenshots

[Preferences section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FRXp.png)
[JRE System library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkOb4.png)
[lib folder of jdk containing tools.jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REDle.png)

I tried changing jre to jdk and tried adding com.sun.tools dependencies in pom.xml still no results

[Folder where eclipse is trying to pick tools.jar from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3e9D.png)

**POM.xml**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.optum</groupId>
<artifactId>ETS_SATDD_Project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name></name>
<description></description>
<dependencies>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reports</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.optum.synergy</groupId>
    <artifactId>synergy-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.emory.mathcs.backport/com.springsource.edu.emory.mathcs.backport -->
    <!--
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.emory.mathcs.backport/com.springsource.edu.emory.mathcs.backport -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version> -->
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId> 
    <version>2.13.4</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.54</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId> oracle </groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId> 
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath> 
        </dependency> -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
        <version>8.0.16</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.jslsolucoes</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId> 
        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>2.0b4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>bson</artifactId> 
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rallydev.rest</groupId>
        <artifactId>rally-rest-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
        <version>1.48</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-excelant -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
        <!-- <scope>system</scope> -->
        <!--
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/httpclient-4.5.2.jar</systemPath> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.4</version>
        <!-- <scope>system</scope> -->
        <!--
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/httpcore-4.4.4.jar</systemPath> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
        <!-- <scope>system</scope> -->
        <!--
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/httpmime-4.5.2.jar</systemPath> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <!-- <scope>system</scope> -->
        <!--
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar</systemPath> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <!--<repository> <id>Your repository's ID</id> <name>Your repository's 
        name</name> <url>URL of the repository containing the LeanFT jar files</url> 
        </repository> -->
</repositories>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>lib/*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>

            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <!--<parenttunnel>${parenttunnel}</parenttunnel>-->
                    <!--<tunnelIdentifier>${tunnelIdentifier}</tunnelIdentifier>-->
                    <!--<environment>${environment}</environment>-->
                    <!--<ms_id>${ms_id}</ms_id>
                    <ms_pwd>${ms_pwd}</ms_pwd>-->

                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <!-- <suiteXmlFiles>
                                   TestNG
                suite XML files
                <suiteXmlFile>Run_All_Features.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles> -->

                <!-- <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>${basedir}/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles> -->
                <!-- c:\Temp>java org.testng.TestNG -groups regressiontest -
                testname AllTests-->
                <!--<groups>regressiontest</groups> -->
                <!-- <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackT;race> -->
                <!--<suitename>AllTests</suitename>-->
                <!-- <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                      Build with
                '-DskipTests=true' to bypass test execution @ build time
                Default: false
                     <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore> -->
                <includes>
                    <include>org.optum.ETSTestRunner.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- <executions>
                    <execution>
        <id>Runnerclass</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions> -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>appmodels</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        build-helper-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.10,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <suiteXmlFile>${basedir}/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
</properties>
```

Problem view

[Problem view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3e9D.png)

Comment: Your image of where the tools.jar file is does not match the location where it appears to be missing. It the jar file physically where Maven is looking for it?

Comment: There is [this Maven dependency `com.sun:tools:0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun/tools/0) and there is a `tools.jar` which is part of the Java 8 JDK, but not of a Java 8 JRE. Right-click your project and choose _Maven > Update Project..._ If this does not help, show your `pom.xml`.

Comment: First the dependency to tools:0 is simply wrong... a tools jar is part of the jdk...furthermore that means your setup/plugins etc. are very old because the need for tools jar is already showing it's really old... should be upgraded... also the JDK version 8.0.292 is also not up-to-date... also seeing things like ant-launcher etc. which really old ... is this really a Maven project? Please show the pom file...

Comment: @nitind I have added the screenshot of the folder my eclipse is trying to pick tools.jar from i have the jar there also but somehow it's not picking it up

Comment: I cannot attach my pom.xml since this i am using my work lapy so i am putting up the screenshots please have a look and let me know if you have any solutions

Comment: @howlger i tried adding the maven dependency that you pinned but still no luck and i also tried updating the project still no luck

Comment: The red exclamation mark means that your project is not configured correctly. You have to fix this first (the error message can be found in the _Problems_ view). Please show the `pom.xml` as text and tell the exact version of Eclipse (are you sure your Eclipse is up to date?). According to [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd8JZ.png) your Eclipse installation or workspace seems to be broken or misconfigured. For what reason do you need `tools.jar`?

Comment: I am using below version

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)

Comment: i have added pom.xml above please have a look

Comment: all my errors i related to tools.jar itself please have a look at the screenshot of problem view